# Facebook graph api friend list not complete

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api to retrieve my friend list.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=

I noticed it is not returning all friends, e.g. I have 194 friends according to facebook.com, but the api call is only returning 189.

Additional Information. I just checked XBox 360's facebook implementation too, it shows only 189 friends for me, even though facebook.com is showing 194 friends. It looks like graph api is not exposing the full friend list.

Anybody has any ideas to fix this ?

Comment: I hope the facebook graph api returns only 100 users in the first call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A user can "turn off all platform apps" and hide himself from all applications. It looks like 5 of your friends chose to turn that off.

The setting is under:

Privacy Settings > Apps and Websites > Apps you use > "Turn off all apps"